# Typescript Array is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I got a function which should save multiple JSON Objects into an Array of the Type "Contact"

```
getContacts(){
    let self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/chat/contacts/",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(response){
            let obj = response;
            let i = 1;
            let contacts: Contact[] = [];
            for (let key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    let val = obj[key];
                    contacts[i].id = val["id"]; //<-- contacts[i] is undefinded
                    contacts[i].partner = val["partnerId"];
                    contacts[i].name = val["name"];
                    contacts[i].type = val["type"];
                    console.log(contacts[i]);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

At the marked point it says

> contacts[i] is undefinded

How do i have to initialize the Array to make it working?

Here is the **Contact** Class:

```
class Contact extends BaseModel{
    static CCO_ID = "id";
    static CCO_PARTNER = "partner";
    static CCO_NAME = "name";
    static CCO_TYPE = "type";


    partner: Number;
    name: String;
    type: Number;
}
```

Comment: use contacts.push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need first to define that `contacts[i]` is an object and then use it's properties.

And one more thing, you are starting from index `1`, in Javascript array's index is starting from `0`. Be aware if that is not intentionally.

```
let val = obj[key];
contacts[i] = new Contact(); // <-- Look here
contacts[i].id = val["id"];
contacts[i].partner = val["partnerId"];
contacts[i].name = val["name"];
contacts[i].type = val["type"];
console.log(contacts[i]);
```